# Is it possible to pass an empty string to an action method with a routed URL segment rather than a query string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller class `Movie`. One of its action method is given as follows:

```
    public string ActionMethod(string id)
    {

        if (id == null)
        {

            return "null";
        }

        if (id == string.Empty)
        {

            return "empty";
        }

        return "neither null nor empaty";
    }
```

Is it possible to pass an empty string to an action method with a routed URL segment rather than a query string?

Note that `http://localhost:21068/Movies/ActionMethod?id=` can do that but it uses a query string. In addition, it is not allowed to modify the action method. :-)

Comment: pass a special sequence of chars or add a new parameter that will indicate the `ActionMethod` contains string.Empty

Comment: @JesseJames: please show it with a code, I cannot understand. Sorry.

Comment: You are being fed by HTTP/HTML which do not really have distinct concepts for NULL and Empty. So you shouldn't be wanting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear about what you're trying to achieve, but you can probably do it by specifying routes appropriately in Global.asax.cs.  As a contrived example, the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "", 
    "{controller}/{action}/id/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } 
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }             
    );
```

lets you use:

```
http://localhost:21068/Movies/ActionMethod        - id is null
http://localhost:21068/Movies/ActionMethod/id/    - id is an empty string
http://localhost:21068/Movies/ActionMethod/id/123 - id is a nonempty string
```

If you state what URLs you want to allow and how to map them, someone will no doubt suggest how you can set up your routes.

Answer (score 0):

Dont pass any querystring if ur ID is empty. like

```
    http://localhost:21068/Movies/ActionMethod
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a query string, have you considered using a form? I haven't tested this, but give it a go:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionMethod", "YourControllerName", "GET")) {
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="submitForm" />
  }
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460344(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score -2):

I think you can pass nullable parameter like:

```
public string ActionMethod(string? id)
```

and than don't pass any query string as:

```
http://localhost:21068/Movies/ActionMethod
```

Comment: string is not a value type and is not nullable.

Comment: Lolz yeh, after viewing this answer of mine, I was like :-O Did I say it?